# MySQL with stock maintain

Tags: mysql

I have a simple program to manage fuel issued status to some of vehicles

That is include following tables

## store_item

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| item_id | item_name | status |
+---------+-----------+--------+
|       1 | Diesel    |      1 |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

## tbl_vehicle

```
+------------+------------+
| vehicle_id | vehicle_no |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |       4545 |
|          2 |       4546 |
|          3 |       4547 |
|         18 |       4548 |
+------------+------------+
```

## store_update_stock

```
+-----------------+------------+---------+--------+
| update_stock_id | bill_date  | bill_no | status |
+-----------------+------------+---------+--------+
|               1 | 2019-09-25 |     123 |      1 |
|               2 | 2019-09-26 |     456 |      1 |
+-----------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

## store_update_stock_details

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | status |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------+
|                       1 |               1 |    1 | 900 |      1 |
|                       2 |               2 |    1 | 800 |      1 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------+
```

## tbl_fuel

```
+---------+------------+-------------+------+----------+
| fuel_id | vehicle_id | issued_date | item | fuel_qty |
+---------+------------+-------------+------+----------+
|       1 |          2 | 2019-09-25  |    1 |       50 |
|       2 |          2 | 2019-09-25  |    1 |       50 |
|       3 |         18 | 2019-09-26  |    1 |       25 |
|       4 |          2 | 2019-09-27  |    1 |       50 |
+---------+------------+-------------+------+----------+
```

## I used the following Code

```
select sum(store_update_stock_details.qty) - tbl_fuel.fuel_qty  as qty
            from store_update_stock_details
            inner join store_update_stock on store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id=store_update_stock.update_stock_id
           join store_item on store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id
            join tbl_fuel on store_item.item_id=tbl_fuel.item
           where store_update_stock.status=1
           group by store_item.item_id
```

## Desired Out

```
+------+
| qty  |
+------+
| 1525 |
+------+
```

But the code generates the following output

```
+------+
| qty  |
+------+
| 6750 |
+------+
```

I can not understand what may be going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I don't understand the fuel table. Perhaps it could/should be redesigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your query is that because you have multiple rows in `tbl_fuel` that match the same `item` as in the stock update details table, you end up with multiple rows in the result set which is being summed (hence the larger than expected result). To work around this, you need to do your sums by item in each table individually, and then subtract the results:

```
select susd.qty - tf.fuel_qty  as qty
from (select susd.item, sum(susd.qty) AS qty
      from store_update_stock_details susd
      join store_update_stock sus on sus.update_stock_id = susd.update_stock_id
      where sus.status = 1
      group by item) susd
join store_item si on susd.item = si.item_id
join (select item, sum(fuel_qty) AS fuel_qty
      from tbl_fuel
      group by item) tf on si.item_id=tf.item
```

Output:

```
qty
1525
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9q6FdxtF8G7mR7WXWgudtN/0)

Comment: @mcode it's not appropriate to edit an answer with what is effectively another question. Instead, just post a new question, referring back to this one.